# Specify the distribution of two discrete independent variables

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-analysis

So I'm preparing for a reexamination for an introductory statistics course, last time I had trouble finding a way to specify the distribution of variables/vectors. So my question is, maybe a more general way of specifying what distribution they have and maybe using this exercise as an example.

$X$ and $Y$ are **independent** discrete stochastic variables, with probability functions

$$p_X(0) = P\{X=0\} = \frac 14; \quad p_X(1) = P\{X=1\} = \frac 34.$$

$$p_Y(0) = P\{Y=0\} = \frac 14; \quad p_Y(1) = P\{Y=1\} = \frac 34.$$

I need to specify the distribution of $X + Y$.

Comment: What are the possible values of $X+Y$? Pick the smallest value of $X+Y$ on your list. Can you figure out what the values $X$ and $Y$ must be in order to produce this value of $X+Y$? If so, and the values are $a$ and $b$, can you figure out what $P\{X=a, Y=b\} = P[\{X=a\}\cap \{Y=b\}]$ is? Hint: _independence._

Comment: How do I find the possible values of X+Y? I have a probability function of the vector (X,Y) and the probability functions of the two independent variables. Is X+Y simple the results of the joint probability function? In that case the lowest value is 1/16 where p_X,Y(0,0). Sorry for being a noob!

Comment: $X$ can take on values $0$ and $1$ **only**. So can $Y$. If $X+Y=0$, can you figure out what the values of $X$ and $Y$ _must_ have been in order to produce a $0$ value for $X+Y$?

Comment: So X and Y must be zero, therefore x and y must be anything but 0 and 1. Right?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood your question as being, the probability of X+Y must be zero. If I use the p(x)=P(X=x) for x \in real numbers.
Therefore both x and y must be 0 to make X+Y = 0. 
If a and b = 0, then P{X=0,Y=0}=p_X,Y(0,0)=1/16?

Comment: **Random variables** take on values depending on the outcome of the experiment. In this case, you are being told that $X$ and $Y$ (note upper case) can take on values $0$ and $1$ only; no other values can occur. $X$ and $Y$ (note upper case) both **must** have had value $0$ in order for $X+Y$ (note upper case) to be $0$. You are **told** that $P\{X=0\} = P\{Y=0\} = \frac 14$ and that the events are $\{X=0\}$ and $\{Y=0\}$ are **independent making the probability that **both** $X$ and $Y$ being $0$ (and so $X+Y$ being $0$) equal $\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove $x$ and $y$ which seem to be the source of your confusion.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense, I was a bit confused about the wording before, sorry about that. So how can i use this to specify the distribution? I have seen only answers to other exercises like this and it is expected to return something like X+Y ~ b(2, 0.3).

Answer (score 0):

The probability space for X+Y = S = {0,1,2}, through the independence assumption we can calculate the event of $P(X = 0, Y=0) = P(X=0)*P(Y=0)$ therefore the following holds:

$P(X+Y = 0) = P(0 + 0 = 0) = P_x(0)*p_y(0) = 1/16$
$P(X+Y = 1) = P(1 + 0 = 1) | P(0 + 1 = 1) = P_x(1)*P_y(0) + P_x(0)*P_y(1) = 3/4*1/4 + 1/4*3/4 = 3/16 + 3/16 = 6/16 = 3/8$
$P(X+Y = 2) = P(1 + 1 = 2) = P_x(1)*P_y(1) = 3/4*3/4 = 9/16$

In general cases you can use the convolution sum (see, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)

Comment: I need to specify the distribution in terms of another common distribution, ex. X+Y ~ b(2,0.3) or N(1,10) or something like that. Is there a general way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could model your original probability functions for X and Y separately as binomial distributions and then use the convolution sum to derive a new binomial distribution. But the general way of doing this is using a convolution sum.

Comment: Why should I model them as binomial distributions and not something else? Is there some way of plotting it and looking at graphs of other distributions to know what kind of distribution it is. I have no idea how to use the convolution article, sadly.

Comment: Because you have a finite set with two possibilities 0 and 1. Therefore, $B(n,p)=(n ncr k)p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = (2 ncr k)0.25^k0.75^{n-k}$ is the probability of selecting $k$ times 0 in your population. (Assume that you draw your samples with replacement). The convolution sum is defined as $\sum^N_{k=0} P(X=n-k)*P(Y=k)$ with N={0,1,2} (calculating all the possible ways to obtain a value N)

Comment: Whoops, the binomial equation should be formulated like this $B(n,p)={n \choose k}p^k(1−p)^{n−k}={2 \choose k}0.25^k0.75^{2−k}$